# How to avoid returning pointers in a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Assume I have a class A that has say 3 methods. So the first methods assigns some values to the first array and the rest of the methods in order modify what is computed by the previous method. Since I wanted to avoid designing the methods that return an array (pointer to local variable) I picked 3 data member and store the intermediate result in each of them. Please note that this simple code is used for illustration.

```
class A
{
public: // for now how the class members should be accessed isn't important 
int * a, *b, *c;

A(int size)
{
    a = new int [size];
    b = new int [size];
    c = new int [size];
}

void func_a()
{ 
    int j = 1;

    for int(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        a[i] = j++;   // assign different values
}

void func_b()
{
    int k = 6;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        b[i] = a[i] * (k++);
}

void func_c()
{
    int p = 6;

    for int (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        c[i] = b[i] * (p++);
}
};
```

Clearly, if I have more methods I have to have more data members.

** I'd like to know how I can re-design the class (having methods that return some values and) at the same time, the class does not have the any of two issues (returning pointers and have many data member to store the intermediate values)

Comment: This is not creating an array `a=new int (size)`

Comment: Your code doesn't return any pointers anyway. And if you don't want to store intermediate values as class members, don't do that . Can you describe what your class is trying to achieve? If you just want to do a series of calculations you can do that in a function

Comment: @Adrian If `b` or `c` fail to allocate memory in your constructor, you have a memory leak.

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to be able to modify a single array with no class-level attributes and without returning any pointers.  Your above code can be modified to be a single function, but I've kept it as 3 to more closely match your code.

```
void func_a(int[] arr, int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = i+1;
}

void func_b(int[] arr, int size){
    int k = 6;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] *= (k+i);
}

//this function is exactly like func_b so it is really unnecessary
void func_c(int[] arr, int size){
    int p = 6;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] *= (p+i);
}
```

But if you just want a single function:

```
void func(int[] arr, int size){
    int j = 6;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = (i+1) * (j+i) * (j+i);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't need to.  j is being added to i, which does increment

Comment: I found it could be reduced to a single expression, but it doesn't seem simpler.  `arr[i] = i*i*i + 13*i*i + 48*i + 36;`

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities. If you want each function to return a new array of values, you can write the following:

```
std::vector<int> func_a(std::vector<int> vec){
    int j = 1;
    for (auto& e : vec) {
        e = j++;
    }
    return vec;
}
std::vector<int> func_b(std::vector<int> vec){      
    int j = 6;
    for (auto& e : vec) {
        e *= j++;
    }
    return vec;     
}
std::vector<int> func_c(std::vector<int> vec){
    //same as func_b
}
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec(10);
    auto a=func_a(vec);
    auto b=func_b(a);
    auto c=func_c(b);
    //or in one line
    auto r = func_c(func_b(func_a(std::vector<int>(10))));
}
```

Or you can apply each function to the same vector:

```
void apply_func_a(std::vector<int>& vec){
    int j = 1;
    for (auto& e : vec) {
        e = j++;
    }
}
void apply_func_b(std::vector<int>& vec){
    int j = 6;
    for (auto& e : vec) {
        e *= j++;
    }
}
void apply_func_c(std::vector<int>& vec){
    // same as apply_func_b 
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec(10);
    apply_func_a(vec);
    apply_func_b(vec);
    apply_func_c(vec);
}
```

I'm not a big fan of the third version (passing the input parameter as the output):

```
 std::vector<int>& func_a(std::vector<int>& vec)
```

Most importantly, try to avoid C-style arrays and use `std::vector` or `std::array`, and don't use `new`, but `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared`

Answer (score 0):

This solution in other answers is better, if you are going to allocate memory then do it like this (and test it!) also if you are not using the default constructor and copy constructor then hide them, this will prevent calling them by accident

```
class A{
private:
A(const &A){}
A() {}//either define these or hide them as private
public: 
    int * a, *b, *c;
    int size;
    A(int sz) {
        size = sz;
        a = new int[size];
        b = new int[size];
        c = new int[size];
    }
    ~A()
    {
        delete[]a;
        delete[]b;
        delete[]c;
    }
//...
};
```